# What could cause the String format of Datetime to differ between a scratch org and a production environment if the API for all involved classes match?

Tags: apex, api

We have some classes that take a Datetime value and change it to a String. It uses .format() to do this.

Apparently, in API 45 the string format was changed to include a comma like '5/19/2023, 7:17 AM'. This is how the production environments are returning it, but our scratch orgs return it without the comma like '5/19/2023 7:17 AM'.

Several of the classes involved in this process are on API versions prior to 45. But, I have checked all the API version deployed in the scratch orgs and production environment every one of them matches between the two. Every class, trigger, and page involved in this particular process are on matching APIs between the scratch org and production org.

We have figured out a solution to the issue this difference is causing in our environments - to account for the possibility that there might or might not be a comma. I'm just dumbfounded as to why there is even a difference.

(for clarity, executing anonymous apex `Datetime.format()` return the same thing.)

Edit: It is worth mentioning that the locale of every user in both orgs is set to `English (United States)`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the locale of the user:

Setup -> Users -> your user -> Locale:

```
System.debug(Datetime.now().format());
```

For Locale *Ukrainian (Ukraine)* will show `19.05.2023, 05:14`

For Locale *English (United States)* will show `5/19/2023, 5:16 AM`

For Locale *French (Canada)* will show `2023-05-19 05 h 22`

Documentation [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format):

> format()
> Converts the date to the local time zone and returns the converted date as a formatted string using the locale of the context user. If the time zone cannot be determined, GMT is used.

Also, check this **ICU Locale Formats** (that set comma in datetime formats) release update:

It can be disabled from Setup -> Release Updates -> Enable ICU Locale Formats -> Get Started -> Disable Test Run.

ICU Locale Formats (that set comma in datetime formats) Enforcement Scheduled: Spring '24.

Comment: that is actually a really good thought, another engineer on our team mentioned that as well. But, I should have mentioned in my post that I also checked the locale. Both are set to `English (United States)`. In fact, to be thorough, I checked the locale of every user in both orgs and they're all English (United States). ‍♂️

Comment: @TommyPrevatt Oh, got it, updated the answer.

Comment: Comma will be enforced in datetime formats: `Enforcement Scheduled: Spring '24`

Comment: Oh wow. That's a great find. That was a difference between the orgs with the production environment having it on and the scratch org having it off. However, after testing it, the strings are still formatted differently. 

Comment: Strange, when I have enabled it on and off for the scratch orgs, I had both results with and without commas :-?

Comment: Disabled Test Run: 5/19/2023 6:06 AM. Enabled Test Run: 5/19/2023, 6:04 AM.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference when I execute `String dt = Datetime.now().format(); System.debug(dt);` with Test Run enabled vs. disabled - I just double checked that. But the particular issue mentioned in my post still remains.

Comment: But what is the initial issue in the post? The question was: why is there a difference. The answer is `ICU Locale Formats`, they should be enabled everywhere and the comma should be present. Then what is the `particular issue mentioned in my post still remains`? :)